# Embedding Javascript in PHP With Brackets

Tags: php, javascript

Alright so I've been trying to echo some JavaScript for the fancybox window to popup if a user logs in or out. This is what I have so far, but it keeps throwing a server error.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<?php
$msg = $_GET['msg'];
if(isset($msg['0']));  {
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
$.fancybox.open([
{
    href : \'m.php?=0\',
    title : \'Successfully Logged In!\'
}    
], {
padding : 0   
});
</script>';
}
else if (isset($msg['1'])); {
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
$.fancybox.open([
{
    href : \'m.php?=1\',
    title : \'Successfully Logged Out!\'
}    
], {
padding : 0   
});
</script>';
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should provide the error server throws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with the brackets.  PHP won't echo out multiple lines of code.  In order to do what you're trying to do you need to set up a variable and then echo that out:

```
$myVar = "";
$myVar .= "<script src='text/javascript'>";
$myVar .= "blah blah blah...";

echo $myVar;
```

Comment: you can also build it over multiple lines, which I often do, like `$myVar = "<script>"."blah blah"."</script>";` but with newlines at each `.`. Just to save some characters.

Answer (score 1):

Don't echo out the script, do something like this.

```
<?php
$msg = $_GET['msg'];
if(isset($msg['0']));  { ?>

<script>
//JS
</script>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This is how you embed JS with php based on a condition

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($msg['0']));  {
```

Semicolon there? I think not. Besides is message an array? Maybe you wanted to do:

```
$msg = isset($_GET['msg']) ? $_GET['msg'] : false;
if($msg === '0')  {
```

Comment: It's not in an array, when the user logs in from login.php i want it to use php header and redirect them to index.php?msg=0. When they are redirected to index.php?msg=0 then i want the fancybox to popup saying successfully logged in. and the same for logout on logout.php.